# SQLite DatabaseHelper class

Tags: android, sqlite

when we create SQLite database from an android application can use a DatabaseHelper class which extend SQLiteOpenHelper.

My constructor is as follows

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context)  
{
      super(context, dbName, null, DATABASE_VERSION);  
}
```

Then the onCreate() method

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    String qry = "CREATE TABLE DEPT(dept_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, deptName TEXT)";   
    db.execSQL(qry);
    InsertDepts(db); 
}
```

But when i create an instance of the DatabaseHelper class, my database havent created yet.

I believe when I create an Object from this class, the constructor executes and since no database created yet it will create database and execute onCreate() method. So definitely an database must be created.

Or untill we execute the following code doesn't it execute the onCreate() method, even if we create an object from the class.

```
databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase()
```

Can anyone please explain the execution order of the databasehelper class.

Comment: +1 for using the `SQLiteHelper`-class.

Answer (score 1):

You create an instance of your `DatabaseHelper`-class, which causes the constructor to be executed. The constructor will execute the mother-classes constructor (`SQLiteOpenHelper`), which will then check if the Database-file already exists.

If it exists, nothing is done and your object is created.

If it doesn't exist, the Database-file is created and the `onCreate`-method is called.

You say, your Database doesn't exist. Are you getting any errors in the LogCat? Also, have you tried [accessing the Database using the adb](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite)?

Comment: I Checked whether the database has created by using the file explorer in the following path.      /data/data/package_name/databases

Comment: @JibW - some devices store app databases in a different directory to the app, so your database may not be in the location you are looking.

Answer (score 0):

Order should be like this ([as reads `SQLiteOpenHelper` javadoc](http://C%3a%5CJava%5Candroid-sdk-windows%5Cdocs%5Creference%5Candroid%5Cdatabase%5Csqlite%5CSQLiteOpenHelper.html))

1. Constructor
2. During 1st call of `openReadableDatabase()` or `openWritableDatabase()` will be called `onCreate`
3. Then will called `onOpen`

**Added**

Just checked sources of SQLiteOpenHelper constructor and it reads:

```
public SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        if (version < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Version must be >= 1, was " + version);

        mContext = context;
        mName = name;
        mFactory = factory;
        mNewVersion = version;
    }
```

In contrary `openReadableDatabase`/`OpenWritableDatabase` sources consists calls to `openOrCreateDatabase()` - so constructor doesn't call `onCreate`

Comment: In your step no 1, When call the constructor, will it call the onCreate() method if there is no database( When calling for the first time)

Comment: Use the source Luke (look addendum above)

Comment: @JibW - correct, your `onCreate` is _only_ called if the database file does not exist. This means that if the file exists but is corrupt, or even zero-length, `onCreate` will still not be called, so you also need to have code to gracefully handle the case of a corrupt database.

Comment: @ barmaley:  But when I call constructor the databse doen't cretae. In the Obove code. But if I call [ databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase() ] method it creates. I am confussed because normally for the first time when call constructor it call the onCreate() method according to my knowledge. can You see any place where I have gone wrong in my code

Comment: @JibW: it's easy to justify order of calling - just put log statements in constructor, in onCreate and in openWritableDatabase. That would be better, huh?

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this

http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/01/creating-multiple-sqlite-database.html