# Android - SQLite rawQuery Listview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-sqlite

I am trying to query all the users data that belong to him uniquely. through FK_ID of the user in the notes table.

```
// Listing all notes

public Cursor listNotes() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = help.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.query(help.NOTE_TABLE, new String[]{help.COLUMN_TITLE,help.COLUMN_BODY, help.COLUMN_DATE}, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }

   return c;

 }



// Count how many Notes user has
public int NoteCount() {

    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + help.NOTE_TABLE;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
// Updating single contact
public void editNote(long id, String title, String body) {

    ContentValues edit = new ContentValues();
    edit.put(help.COLUMN_TITLE, title);
    edit.put(help.COLUMN_BODY, body);

    open();
    db.update(help.NOTE_TABLE, edit, help.NOTES_ID + "=" + id, null);
    close();
}

// Deleting single note
public void deleteNote(long id) {
    open();
    db.delete(help.NOTE_TABLE, help.NOTES_ID + "=" + id, null);
    close();
}
```

}

I have a tab that will then return all the users data uniquely to him. This tab is a fragment.the Method populateList() will be called onCreateView

```
    public void populateList(){

    Cursor cursor = control.listNotes();
    getActivity().startManagingCursor(cursor);

    //Mapping the fields cursor to text views
    String[] fields = new String[]{help.COLUMN_TITLE,help.COLUMN_BODY, help.COLUMN_DATE};
    int [] text = new int[] {R.id.item_title,R.id.item_body, R.id.item_date};
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list_layout,cursor, fields, text,0);

    //Calling list object instance
    listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This is a null pointer. Am i passing the data wrong
    Cursor cursor = control.listNotes();

Comment: You have 2 good answers already. Are you still working on this problem? If you are, what specific issue do you have now, related to the posted question?

Comment: @theOriginalAndroid I will update my code, Cursor cursor = control.listNotes(); is a null pointer

Comment: Given the sample posted code in the answers, it would help if you try something and post ALL the relevant code that you wrote (with bugs or not), code should be relevant to the issue. This way, you'll get a better reputation/image in this blog community.

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid I have updated my code, and shown all my code. If possible I want to try and use ListFragment.

Comment: I am not familiar with the DatabaseHelper as you're depending on it very much. Make sure that the temp database and table is created before you even query the table with listNotes(). Investigate DatabaseHelper using SQLite. Here is a discussion it and hopefully that will give you an idea, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609827/sqlite-databasehelper-class.

Answer (score 0):

Your `listNotes` method should look like :

```
public Cursor listNotes(long userId) {
        Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(yourTodoTableURI, new String[]{help.COLUMN_TITLE,help.COLUMN_BODY, help.COLUMN_DATE}, help.COLUMN_USER_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(userId)} , null);
        return c;
    }
```

Comment: it doesnt recognize getActivity().getContentResolver() ListNotes is in a class with all my queries to get user data not in a fragment

Comment: Ok, so you need a Context to call getContentResolver() like yourContext.getContentResolver()...

Comment: Hm what context would that be? All i have is reference from DBHelper and instace of SQLItedatabase. How can i pass it to my listview

Comment: Ok, so you can use : Cursor c = db.query(yourTodoTableName, new String[]{help.COLUMN_TITLE,help.COLUMN_BODY, help.COLUMN_DATE}, help.COLUMN_USER_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(userId)} , null, null, null);

Comment: Then would i need to change populateList how can i obtain this

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public List<String> getAllTask(int userID){  

      String query = "Select * from tablename where ID =" + userID; 
          cursor = db.query(); //do your code here
      int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(tablename.ID));

      List<String> task = new ArrayList<String>();

      String query = "Select * from tableTask where ID =" + id";
      cursor = db.query(); //
      if (cursor != null) {
          cursor.movetofirst();
          // do your code here

          do{
          String task = cursor.get......

          task.add(task);
          }while(cursor.movetonext);
      }

return task;
}
```

Comment: will populateList method change? do I need the cursor?

Comment: You can create your own User class and add a field there `private ArrayList<String> mTask;`. It will be much easier to display data in ListView that way...

Comment: I have created the user without getters, I simply used put() to add each user as a new row